# Abnormal record with strange font

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm struggling a bit in the best way to describe this question. I have a set of zip code values that are currently stored as a varchar data type. I am trying to clean the column and store it in a different table with an int data type. Running `CAST` on the column gives me a conversion error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 52 Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '６００９９' to data type int.

Upon narrowing this down, I find this record with a strange font on row 425. I've never seen anything like this nor can I find much about it from a google search. All other records will convert just fine if I exclude this particular record. Can anyone point me in a direction here?

[image]

Comment: Use the [`UNICODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/unicode-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function see what is actually stored there.

Comment: What happens if you first cast as `varchar` then cast as `int`?

Comment: FYI, those are fullwidth Unicode digits. Converting to varchar like @Stu suggested will translate those to the similar ASCII character digits where they will be convertable to int. But converting a postal code value to an integer has a code smell.

Comment: Thanks for the informative responses everyone!

Comment: @DanGuzman Could convert one character at a time though, that would preserve things like leading 0's

Comment: @Charlieface, the actual number of leading zeros will be forgotten once stored in the int data type regardless of the conversion method.

Comment: When faced with "weird" character data of unknown provenance, I like to cast to varbinary so I can see what bytes are being stored. Just last week, that helped me see that there were ASCII `NUL` values being stored in one of my columns in production!

Comment: Considering that a zip code is made up of the characters 0-9, why use an `nvarchar` in the first place? A `char(5)` with a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` that ensures that no alpha characters are entered would seem a much better idea.

Comment: Storing zip codes for the US as an int is going to fail big time. There are a few states in the NE (Connecticut, Maine, NJ etc) that have valid zip codes with a leading 0. If you store those values as ints the leading 0 will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvarchar column allowed a unicode value to be stored with characters meant to represent ASCII values.